# Matching line variable with numrefs list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help on my code. The following are my current issues:

1. I need to get the matched value in `numref`s when variable line matches it, example given below.
2. I am not sure if I am constructing the `if`-statement correctly.

Code:

```
import subprocess

def p4 (base_num):

    numrefs = ['nums/89/202089/4', 'nums/39/205739/2', 'nums/94/195594/6']
    num_ignore = [150362, 147117, 147441, 143446, 200914]
    ''''
    num_ids.txt
    202089
    205739
    195594
    202090
    202092
    202091
    202084
    202088
    202086
    202076
    202083
    206057
    206056
    '''

    with open('./num_ids.txt', 'rb') as f:
    # Iterate over the file itself
        for line in f:
            num = int(line)
            if num > base_num and num not in num_ignore and line in numrefs:
                #get the match when line matches numrefs
                #if line is 20289,it should match the value nums/89/202089/ in  num_refs and print it here,how can I do it?
                print "OVER"

def main():
    base_num=203456
    p4(base_num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The rules are not clear. What is the expected output? Can you use mathematical language to describe the problem?

Comment: @PauloScardine - for loop is looping over each value in num_ids.txt(sample input is shown above),if has 3 conditions,one condition is to check if there is a match of value in num_ids.txt with numrefs list..it should print nums/89/202089/4 if line is 202089,nums/39/205739/2 if line is 205739...so on

Comment: There are several ways to improve your question: 1) your sample code should be properly indented and executable. 2) you should explain what have you tried, what result you got and why you think it is not working.

Comment: @PauloScardine - I actually did that..let me repost with more meaningful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, your code is failing for two reasons:

1. The string identified by `line` will end with a `\n`: this needs to be `strip`ped before searching for the within `numrefs`.
2. `line in numrefs` will always fail because the strings in `numrefs` are longer. It looks like you want to search within these strings.

Here is a version of `p4()` that addresses these two issues.

```
def p4(base_num):
    numrefs = ['nums/89/202089/4', 'nums/39/205739/2', 'nums/94/195594/6']
    num_ignore = [150362, 147117, 147441, 143446, 200914]

    with open('./num_ids.txt', 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            text = line.strip()  # Trim trailing whitespace and newline
            num = int(text)
            if (num > base_num
                    and num not in num_ignore
                    # Check for any substring in list of strings
                    and any(text in numref for numref in numrefs)):
                print text
```

If you need to print the found `numref` string (if it exists), then change the `if`-statement to:

```
            if num > base_num and num not in num_ignore:
                result = [numref for numref in numrefs if text in numref]
                if result:
                    print result[0]
```

This `if`-statement should be extracted into its own, *testable*, method.